# Removing one or multiple keys from a dictionary

Tags: python, python-3.x

In Scala, to remove one key from a dictionary I need to do (pasted from REPL):

```
scala> Map(9 -> 11, 7 -> 6, 89 -> 43) - 9
res4: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(7 -> 6, 89 -> 43)
```

To remove multiple keys:

```
scala> Map(9 -> 11, 7 -> 6, 89 -> 43) -- Seq(9, 89)
res5: scala.collection.immutable.Map[Int,Int] = Map(7 -> 6)
```

What is the Python way of doing this? (I posted Scala examples because that's the background I come from.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `d` is your dictionary and `k` the key you want to remove:

```
d.pop(k)
```

For example:

```
d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
d.pop("a")
print d
# {'c': 3, 'b': 2}
```

If you want to remove multiple:

```
for k in lst:
    d.pop(k)
```

If you want to do this non-destructively, and get a new dictionary that is a subset, your best bet is:

```
s = set(lst)
new_dict = {k: v for k, v in d.items() if k not in s}
```

You could use `k not in lst` instead of dealing with `set(lst)`, but using `set` will be faster if the list of items to remove is long.

Comment: Is there a way to get a new dictionary without the specified keys?

Comment: We've been typing the same stuff for five minutes now. Removed my answer, +1 to yours.

Comment: `d.pop(k)` returns the removed item. If this is a side effect you don't need, you can also `del d[k]`.

Comment: @larsmans: Thoughtful of you! (That does tend to happen with this kind of question).

Comment: I was expecting something shorter but this is fine too. Thanks.

Comment: @missingfaktor: I've edited the dictionary comprehension you should use- the version I originally gave was considerably slower (it performed `set(lst)` for every item in the dictionary)

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> d = {"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}
>>> for _ in ['a','c']: del(d[_])
... 
>>> d
{'b': 2}
```